# Why is U the symbol for lattice energy?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, notation, crystallography

I often see $U$ or even $\Delta U$ being the symbol for lattice energy. Why is that? Does it refer to internal energy?

Comment: Yes, it corresponds to the internal energy of the crystal. IUCr uses a more well-thought symbol $U_\mathrm{L}.$

Comment: Why do we use $\Delta U$ and not $\Delta H$? Is the measurement of lattice energy done at constant volume, or something?

Comment: @Quantonium I suppose because the lattice energy it is the internal energy of the lattice.